# How to apply default to all expect commands?

Tags: tcl, expect

Coding CLI unit tests using expect and would like to abstract following `default` block as it applies to all expect blocks.

```
default {
  test_failed
}
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

source ./test.exp

set passphrase "asdasd"
set secret "foo\nbar"

test_label "Should backup secret using Shamir Secret Sharing"

spawn qr-backup.sh --shamir-secret-sharing

expect {
  default {
    test_failed
  }
  -re {Format USB flash drive \(y or n\)\?} {
    sleep 0.1
    send "n\r"
  }
}

expect {
  default {
    test_failed
  }
  -re {\[sudo\] password for pi:} {
    sleep 0.1
    send "$env(password)\r"
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the `expect_before` (or `expect_after`) command.

Comment: Thanks @SchelteBron. Exactly what I was looking for. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the `expect_before` and `expect_after` commands do. In this case it doesn't matter which one you use:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn qr-backup.sh --shamir-secret-sharing

expect_after {
    default {
        test_failed
    }
}

expect {
    -ex {Format USB flash drive (y or n)? } {
        send "n\r"
    }
}

expect {
    -ex {[sudo] password for pi: } {
        send "$env(password)\r"
    }
}
```